# MigLayout seems to override setLocation - how to avoid this?

Tags: java, swing, layout, miglayout

With a `JPanel` using `MigLayout`, when I use `setLocation(x,y);` when dragging another `JPanel` inside this panel, the location of the component is reset to the absolute positioning component constraint (specified when adding the component). For example:

```
this.add(content, "pos 50 50");
...
//dragging
content.setLocation(x,y);
```

When I do this, it successfully changes the x/y location of the content, but is reset again as soon as the outer (this) panel is resized or validated.

I've tried the following code but the panel doesn't move on drag at all:

```
migLayout.setComponentConstraints(content, "pos " + x + " " + y);
```

How can I get around this?
**Thanks.**

Comment: nothing special to MigLayout - a LayoutManager is _supposed_ to locate a component as it deems appropriate (while client code is _not_) For the special case of dragging, you'll need to implement some logic remove/reset the dragged component from the managers control at the start/end of the dragging, maybe move it up into another layer of a LayeredPane and at the end reset the constraints (didn't try, though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the keyword external to the component constraint when you want Miglayout to not place it, like while dragging.

The more general answer is just like Kleopatra say.